# Remove unwanted div from any generated from authenticity_token form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionpack

This should be an easy one but I just cant find the answer!
My Rail Forms generate a div that I want to get rid of

This is the div that rails generate for me

```
   <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713"/><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="Z6UAdFYt3v8d1lx4BNXq5td3OMJ223i+ruKM8Ldb+5s=" /></div>
```

I had a look to some previews questions that were suggesting I should use `form_authenticity_token`

Where and how in the code can I use form_authenticity_token instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Rails are you using?

I don't know why you want to do this. If it's a CSS issue you can just be more specific. I've never needed to do this.
However…

The way to do it in 3.0.9 would be making an initializer and adding this code:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormHelper
        def extra_tags_for_form(html_options)
          snowman_tag = tag(:input, :type => "hidden",
                            :name => "utf8", :value => "&#x2713;".html_safe)

          method = html_options.delete("method").to_s

          method_tag = case method
            when /^get$/i # must be case-insensitive, but can't use downcase as might be nil
              html_options["method"] = "get"
              ''
            when /^post$/i, "", nil
              html_options["method"] = "post"
              token_tag
            else
              html_options["method"] = "post"
              tag(:input, :type => "hidden", :name => "_method", :value => method) + token_tag
          end

          tags = snowman_tag << method_tag
          content_tag(:span, tags, :style => 'margin:0;padding:0;display:inline')
        end
  end
end
```

Comment: i have had a similar CSS issue. I wanted to use the :first-child pseudo-selector. That would not work, as the first child is always the hidden div.